# covariant vectors combination

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

In a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071756035) (p.37) on tensor calculus, an example is given to show that if $T_{i}$ are the components of a covariant vector $\bf{T}$, then $S_{ij}\equiv T_{i}T_{j}-T_{j}T_{i}$ are the components of a skew-symmetric covariant tensor $\bf{S}$. The formal derivation is clear.

My question: wouldn't the expression $T_{i}T_{j}-T_{j}T_{i}$ equal zero identically always here? For example, if I think of a vector like $(T_{i})=(5,2,3)$, then e.g., $T_{2}T_{3}=2\times 3=T_{3}T_{2}=3\times 2=6$ (thus, $S_{23} =S_{32}= 6-6=0$).

What am I missing here?

Comment: If T is indeed a vector it should be written with raised scripts.

Answer (score -1):

In your specific example yes, it will be zero since you have constructed a symmetric tensor, $T_{ij}=T_i T_j=T_jT_i=T_{ji}$

$$T=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 25 & 10 & 15 \\
 10 & 4 & 6 \\
 15 & 6 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Obviously symmetric tensors do not have an asymmetric part. Since they are, erhm, symmetric and all.

A better example would be

$$C=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 10 & -10 & 20 \\
 4 & -4 & 8 \\
 6 & -6 & 12 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now the symmetric part is

$$S_{hj}=\frac{1}{2}(C_{hj}+C_{jh})=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 10 & -3 & 13 \\
 -3 & -4 & 1 \\
 13 & 1 & 12 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

And the skew-symmetric part is

$$T_{hj}=\frac{1}{2}(C_{hj}-C_{hj})=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -7 & 7 \\
 7 & 0 & 7 \\
 -7 & -7 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The tensor $C_{hj}$ is the sum of its so called symmetric and skew-symmetric parts; for instance, one obviously has

$$
C_{hj}=\frac{1}{2}(C_{hj}+C_{jh})+\frac{1}{2}(C_{hj}-C_{jh})
$$

This process is often referred to as symmetrization (or the converse skew-symmetrization for the second part) and can be generalized to an operation involving more than two indices. Given any tensor of type $(r,s)$ with $r>1$ or $s>1$, one can always construct from it a symmetric and a skew-symmetric tensor *in any pair of subscripts*, or *any pair of superscripts*. But **never, ever try to pair a subscript with superscript**. Also, don't feed it after midnight.

Comment: Your answer discusses the concept of symmetrization, which is clear. But my question was about the fact that here we cannot have nonezero terms because we are building the tensor, by definition, from the components of one vector. For example, how would you get your matrix C from a single vector T ?

Comment: You have constructed a *symmetric tensor* since $T_iT_i=T_jT_i$. Obviously every component of the skew-symmetric $\frac12(T_{ij}-T_{ji})$ part will be zero. Hopefully someone else can explain this in a better way.